# Why doesn't embedded Mono execute?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux, reactive

I have a function:

```
private Mono<Void> deleteCommentReply(String id) {
    System.out.println("YES");
    return this.getCommentById(id).flatMap(comment -> {
        System.out.println("YES1");
        // Does some other Mono call, and after them returns Mono.empty();
        return Mono.empty();
    });
}
```

*getCommentById returns Mono, if not found it throws an exception, but no exceptions were thrown, and Ids do exist, so that works fine.

With this code I call it:

```
List<Mono<Void>> monos = new ArrayList<>();
for (String s : comment.getReplyCommentIds()) {
     monos.add(deleteCommentReply(s));
}

Flux<Mono<Void>> deleteReply = Flux.fromIterable(monos);

return deleteReply.then(finalDelete(id, comment));
```

YES prints out the right number of times, but YES1 never prints. Why does embedded Mono never execute? How to fix it?

Also when I call .blockLast() before then, it does execute once successfully (YES and YES1 are printed and is removed from db). So the method itself works, the question is how to call it (and finalDelete() should be called after it is done)?

Comment: @Hulk it returns Mono<Comment>, if not found it throws an exception, but no exceptions were thrown, and Ids do exist, so I don't think that is the problem

Comment: you need to "reach into" and flatten out content of mono's for it to force computation. Instead of Flux<Mono<Void>> you want to create Flux<Void>. Look into Flux#concat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Flux.concat() fixed issues that I was having, now code from the question would look something like this:

```
List<Mono<Void>> monos = new ArrayList<>();

for (String s : comment.getReplyCommentIds()) {
    monos.add(deleteCommentReply(s));
}

Flux<Void> deleteReply = Flux.concat(monos);
return deleteReply.then(finalDelete(id, comment));
```

Using concat all the nested Monos execute.